# How do we get the channel layout syntax from new ffmpeg AVCodecParameters?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

In ffmpeg 6.0 I want to get the channel layout syntax name like:  [FFmpeg Channel Layout Syntax](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#channel-layout-syntax)

Then I could use some filter like **aformat** :

> aformat=sample_fmts=u8|s16:channel_layouts=**stereo**

I did use `AVCodecParameters` get the `ch_layout`, but I don't know how to change it to channel layout syntax, like: **stereo**, or **5.1**.

Is there any function we could get it? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use [av_channel_layout_describe](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__audio__channels.html#gacc7d7d1a280248aafb8f9196c9d4e24f) for getting string describing the channel layout.

`int av_channel_layout_describe(const AVChannelLayout *channel_layout, char *buf, size_t buf_size)`:

> Get a human-readable string describing the channel layout properties.

---

For getting the description, we have to find the channel layout (`AVChannelLayout` structure) of the audio stream first.

- Open an input file and find stream information:

  ```
   avformat_open_input(&avFmtCtx, input_file, nullptr, nullptr)
   avformat_find_stream_info(avFmtCtx, nullptr)
  ```
- Find the index of the relevant audio stream (first audio stream for example), and get codec parameters:

  ```
   int streamIndex = -1;
   for (int si = 0; si < (int)avFmtCtx->nb_streams; si++)
   {
       if (avFmtCtx->streams[si]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
       {
           avCodecParams = avFmtCtx->streams[si]->codecpar;
           streamIndex = si;
           break;
       }
   }
  ```
- Get channel layout description:

  ```
   char chLayoutDescription[128];
   int sts = av_channel_layout_describe(&avCodecParams->ch_layout, chLayoutDescription, sizeof(chLayoutDescription));
  ```

---

Code sample:

```
extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
}

#include <stdio.h>

//Create "stereo.mp4" for testing:
//ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=100 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=1000 -map_channel 1.0.0 -map_channel 2.0.0 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -t 10 stereo.mp4

//Create "six_channels.mp4" for testing:
//ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=100 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=500 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=600 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=700 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=800 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=900 -map_channel 1.0.0 -map_channel 2.0.0 -map_channel 3.0.0 -map_channel 4.0.0 -map_channel 5.0.0 -map_channel 6.0.0 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 6 -t 10 six_channels.mp4


int main()
{
    const char *input_file = "stereo.mp4";              //Output: ch_layout_description = stereo
    //const char *input_file = "six_channels.mp4";      //Output: ch_layout_description = 5.1
    
    AVFormatContext* avFmtCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
    AVStream* avFirstAudioStream = nullptr;    
    AVCodecParameters* avCodecParams = nullptr;

    //https://stackoverflow.com/q/76083629/4926757
    if (avformat_open_input(&avFmtCtx, input_file, nullptr, nullptr) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file with avformat_open_input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(avFmtCtx, nullptr) < 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get stream info with avformat_find_stream_info\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //Find the index of the first audio stream, and get codec parameters
    int streamIndex = -1;
    for (int si = 0; si < (int)avFmtCtx->nb_streams; si++)
    {
        if (avFmtCtx->streams[si]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
        {
            avCodecParams = avFmtCtx->streams[si]->codecpar;
            streamIndex = si;
            break;
        }
    }

    //Get channel layout description:
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    char chLayoutDescription[128];
    int sts = av_channel_layout_describe(&avCodecParams->ch_layout, chLayoutDescription, sizeof(chLayoutDescription));

    if (sts < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: av_channel_layout_describe returned status %d\n", sts); //Error...
        return 1;
    }

    printf("ch_layout_description = %s\n", chLayoutDescription);  //Print channel layout description
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    avformat_free_context(avFmtCtx);
    return 0;
}
```

---

### Update:

**Reading the channel layout of dshow microphone device:**

When reading the channel layout of the microphone, the channel layout description is `2 channels` and not `stereo`.

Looking at `avCodecParams->ch_layout` of `"stereo.mp4"` file, we may see that:

- `order` = `AV_CHANNEL_ORDER_NATIVE`
- `nb_channels` = `2`

Looking at `avCodecParams->ch_layout` of the microphone (using the debugger), we may see that:

- `order` = `AV_CHANNEL_ORDER_UNSPEC`
- `nb_channels` = `2`

We may conclude that the channels order of the microphone is **unspecified**.
When the channels order is unspecified, FFmpeg reports `2 channels` instead of `stereo`.

Looking at my microphone, it looks like the two microphones holds are one very close, and located one above the other (while stereo layout supposed to  be left and right with some distance).
I don't know if there are microphone models that reports `stereo` layout, but `2 channels` layout seems correct for my microphone.

---

Getting the default channel layout for the given number of channels:

We may use `av_channel_layout_default` for getting the default channel layout for the given number of channels (i.e getting `stereo` for 2 channels).

Code sample for getting the default channel layout:

```
char defaultChLayoutDescription[128];
AVChannelLayout default_ch_layout;

av_channel_layout_default(&default_ch_layout, avCodecParams->ch_layout.nb_channels);

sts = av_channel_layout_describe(&default_ch_layout, defaultChLayoutDescription, sizeof(defaultChLayoutDescription));
```

---

Code sample for getting the channel layout of a microphone, and also getting the default layout for 2 channels:

```
extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavutil/avutil.h>
}

#include <stdio.h>

//Create "stereo.mp4" for testing:
//ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=100 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=1000 -map_channel 1.0.0 -map_channel 2.0.0 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -t 10 stereo.mp4

//Create "six_channels.mp4" for testing:
//ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=100 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=500 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=600 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=700 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=800 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=900 -map_channel 1.0.0 -map_channel 2.0.0 -map_channel 3.0.0 -map_channel 4.0.0 -map_channel 5.0.0 -map_channel 6.0.0 -acodec aac -ar 44100 -ac 6 -t 10 six_channels.mp4

//Listing dshow devices:
//ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy

int main()
{
    //const char *input_file = "stereo.mp4";              //Output: ch_layout_description = stereo
    //const char *input_file = "six_channels.mp4";      //Output: ch_layout_description = 5.1


    //Capture dshow microphone
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    avdevice_register_all();
    const char *input_file = "audio=""@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\\wave_{C7D33711-2FD7-4800-8D99-72ED74527121}""";  //Using Alternative name for my audio device.

    const AVInputFormat* ifmt = av_find_input_format("dshow");
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    
    AVFormatContext* avFmtCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
    AVStream* avFirstAudioStream = nullptr;    
    AVCodecParameters* avCodecParams = nullptr;

    //https://stackoverflow.com/q/76083629/4926757
    if (avformat_open_input(&avFmtCtx, input_file, ifmt, nullptr) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file with avformat_open_input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(avFmtCtx, nullptr) < 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get stream info with avformat_find_stream_info\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //Find the index of the first audio stream, and get codec parameters
    int streamIndex = -1;
    for (int si = 0; si < (int)avFmtCtx->nb_streams; si++)
    {
        if (avFmtCtx->streams[si]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)
        {
            avCodecParams = avFmtCtx->streams[si]->codecpar;
            streamIndex = si;
            break;
        }
    }

    
    //Get channel layout description:
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    char chLayoutDescription[128];
    int sts = av_channel_layout_describe(&avCodecParams->ch_layout, chLayoutDescription, sizeof(chLayoutDescription));

    if (sts < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: av_channel_layout_describe returned status %d\n", sts); //Error...
        return 1;
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Get the default channel layout for the given number of channels:
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    char defaultChLayoutDescription[128];
    AVChannelLayout default_ch_layout;

    av_channel_layout_default(&default_ch_layout, avCodecParams->ch_layout.nb_channels);

    sts = av_channel_layout_describe(&default_ch_layout, defaultChLayoutDescription, sizeof(defaultChLayoutDescription));

    if (sts < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: av_channel_layout_describe returned status %d\n", sts); //Error...
        return 1;
    }    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    avformat_close_input(&avFmtCtx);
    avformat_free_context(avFmtCtx);

    fprintf(stderr, "\nchLayoutDescription = %s\n", chLayoutDescription);  //Print channel layout description //2 channels

    fprintf(stderr, "\ndefaultChLayoutDescription = %s\n", defaultChLayoutDescription);  //Print channel layout description //stereo

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

`chLayoutDescription = 2 channels`

`defaultChLayoutDescription = stereo`

---

Note:
The result is the same for FFmpeg 6.0 and FFmpeg 5.1.2 (while FFmpeg 4.4 excludes the function `av_channel_layout_describe`).

Comment: but when I capture my microphone by use`dshow`, it only show: `2 channels`, not `stereo`

Comment: Do you mean that FFmpeg shows 'stereo' layout? I suppose it's FFmpeg default for two channels. I don't think I can fix that...

Comment: I just want to get the syntax name from `AVLayoutChannel` or `AVChannel` as like the aformat filter  `channel_layouts` required.

Comment: Do you mean `s16:channel_layouts=stereo` for example? Or do you mean `FL+FR` for example? In your post you are giving an example `aformat=sample_fmts=u8|s16:channel_layouts=stereo`. The `sample_fmts=u8|s16` part is separated list of sample formats. The `channel_layouts=stereo` part is separated list of channel layouts. Then you are asking "how to change it to channel layout syntax, like: **stereo**, or **5.1**". It looks like what you like to get is the `stereo` or `5.1` as a string. Can you please edit your question to be more clear?

Comment: Hi, I mean like get : `stereo`, or `5.1` as I wroted in my question.

Comment: In my answer, I am showing that using `av_channel_layout_describe`, we can get `stereo` and also `5.1` (as asked). I gave an example for creating `stereo.mp4` sample file and `six_channels.mp4` sample file using FFmpeg CLI. I am showing that for `stereo.mp4`, the output is `stereo` and for `six_channels.mp4` the output is `5.1`. I don't understand why my answer is not what you are looking for.

Comment: as I said before maybe you're answer is really close, but when I capture my microphone by use `dshow`, it only show: `2 channels`, not `stereo`, did you tried capture the microphone in windows as a audio stream?

Comment: As I commented, I am not part of FFmpeg development team. FFmpeg doesn't have the option to return `2 channels` layout status. We can see all the layout options in the [link you have posted](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#channel-layout-syntax) and there is no `2 channels` layout. FFmpeg sees your microphone's channel layout as `stereo`, and there is nothing I can do about it...

Comment: after call you're method `av_channel_layout_describe`, the `chLayoutDescription` get :`2 channels`, why are you saying like I'm lying? I just want to get `stereo` or `5.1` syntax when capture microphone.  if ffmpeg not taht kind of layout where the `2 channels`? do you think I made it up?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you. I thought that `dshow` reports `2 channels` but FFmpeg reports `stereo`. I guess you meant capturing `dshow` device.  But if FFmpeg reports `2 channels`, I still don't have control here.

Comment: We may get the number of channels as an integer. That"s not an issue... Then we may assume that 2 channels applies stereo. How do you know if the correct layout of your  microphone is stereo and 2 channels is incorrect?

Comment: I updated my answer. I managed to reproduce the issue - the layout of my microphone is reported as `2 channels`. Looking at my microphone, it looks like **2 channels** and not **stereo** (the ordering of the two small microphones holes is not left/right so not considered stereo layout). I guess that `2 channels` is the correct channels layout of my microphone... For getting `stereo` as default of 2 channels, we may use `av_channel_layout_default` (see my updated answer).