# Extracting Audio Samples using libavcodec

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, cpython

I'm confused about how to extract double values from data in AVFrame. I'm trying to extract frames. I have tried to examine the source behind the av module, written in CPython, especially for AudioFrame to try and understand where it's decoding samples from: https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/blob/main/av/audio/frame.pyx. The below script works fine, but the bottom C++ program, produces nonsense.

```
import av  

input_file = 'C:\\path\\to\\sound.mp3'
container = av.open(input_file)

# Find audio stream
audio_stream = None
for stream in container.streams:
    if stream.type == 'audio':
        audio_stream = stream
        break

if audio_stream is None:
    print("No audio streams detected")
    container.close()
    exit(1)

# Access audio samples
sampleListL = []
sampleListR = []
for packet in container.demux(audio_stream):
    for frame in packet.decode():
        exit(0)
        sampleListL += frame.to_ndarray()[0].tolist()
        sampleListR += frame.to_ndarray()[1].tolist()

print("Channel L,Channel R")
for s in zip(sampleListL, sampleListR):
    print(str.format("{},{}",s[0],s[1]))

# Cleanup
container.close()



// avcodec-simple-frame-extraction.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.

#include "avcodec-simple-frame-extraction.h"
#include <array>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

using AudioFrameSample = std::array<double, 8>;

static int ReadFramesForAudioFile(const char* filepath)
{
    AVCodecContext* avCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(nullptr);
    AVFormatContext* avFmtCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
    AVStream* avFirstAudioStream = nullptr;
    
    AVCodecParameters* avCodecParams = nullptr;
    if (avformat_open_input(&avFmtCtx, filepath, nullptr, nullptr) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file with avformat_open_input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(avFmtCtx, nullptr) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get stream info with avformat_find_stream_info\n");
        return 1;
    }
    avCodecCtx->request_sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_DBL;
    //find the index of the first audio stream
    int streamIndex = -1;
    for (int si = 0; si < avFmtCtx->nb_streams; si++) {
        if (avFmtCtx->streams[si]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            avCodecParams = avFmtCtx->streams[si]->codecpar;
            streamIndex = si;
            break;
        }
    }
    //find decoder codec for local stream
    const AVCodec* avCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(avCodecParams->codec_id);
    avCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(avCodec);
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(avCodecCtx, avCodecParams);
    avcodec_open2(avCodecCtx, avCodec, nullptr);
    if (streamIndex == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No audio streams detected\n");
    }
    avFirstAudioStream = avFmtCtx->streams[streamIndex];
    //no resampling, just use the same sampling rate as the original codec
    //prepare reading data
    AVPacket* avPacket = av_packet_alloc();
    AVFrame* avFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (avFrame == nullptr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating the frame\n");
        return 1;
    }
    std::vector<AudioFrameSample> mySamples;
    while (av_read_frame(avFmtCtx, avPacket) >= 0) {
        avcodec_send_packet(avCodecCtx, avPacket);
        avcodec_receive_frame(avCodecCtx, avFrame);
        //TODO: Study and use decoding technique in PyAV:
            //https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/blob/main/av/audio/frame.pyx

        for (int ch = 0; ch < avFrame->ch_layout.nb_channels; ch++) {
            for (int s = 0; s < avFrame->linesize[0]; s+=sizeof(double)) {
                double value;
                memcpy(&value, &avFrame->data[ch][s], sizeof(double));
                mySamples.push_back(AudioFrameSample{ value });
            }
        }
    }
    for (auto& f : mySamples) {
        for (int ch = 0; ch < 6; ch++) {
            printf("%0.8f,", f[ch]);
        }
        printf("%0.8f\n", f[7]);
    }
    avcodec_free_context(&avCodecCtx);
    av_packet_free(&avPacket);
    av_frame_free(&avFrame);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2) {
        ReadFramesForAudioFile(argv[1]);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: avcodec-simple-frame-extraction [path]\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's my program in C++, using AVFrame's data directly, trying to convert into double values:

```
// avcodec-simple-frame-extraction.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.

#include "avcodec-simple-frame-extraction.h"
#include <array>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

using AudioFrameSample = std::array<double, 8>;

static int ReadFramesForAudioFile(const char* filepath)
{
    AVCodecContext* avCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(nullptr);
    AVFormatContext* avFmtCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
    AVStream* avFirstAudioStream = nullptr;
    
    AVCodecParameters* avCodecParams = nullptr;
    if (avformat_open_input(&avFmtCtx, filepath, nullptr, nullptr) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file with avformat_open_input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(avFmtCtx, nullptr) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get stream info with avformat_find_stream_info\n");
        return 1;
    }
    avCodecCtx->request_sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_DBL;
    //find the index of the first audio stream
    int streamIndex = -1;
    for (int si = 0; si < avFmtCtx->nb_streams; si++) {
        if (avFmtCtx->streams[si]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            avCodecParams = avFmtCtx->streams[si]->codecpar;
            streamIndex = si;
            break;
        }
    }
    //find decoder codec for local stream
    const AVCodec* avCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(avCodecParams->codec_id);
    avCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(avCodec);
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(avCodecCtx, avCodecParams);
    avcodec_open2(avCodecCtx, avCodec, nullptr);
    if (streamIndex == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No audio streams detected\n");
    }
    avFirstAudioStream = avFmtCtx->streams[streamIndex];
    //no resampling, just use the same sampling rate as the original codec
    //prepare reading data
    AVPacket* avPacket = av_packet_alloc();
    AVFrame* avFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (avFrame == nullptr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating the frame\n");
        return 1;
    }
    std::vector<AudioFrameSample> mySamples;
    while (av_read_frame(avFmtCtx, avPacket) >= 0) {
        avcodec_send_packet(avCodecCtx, avPacket);
        avcodec_receive_frame(avCodecCtx, avFrame);
        //TODO: Study and use decoding technique in PyAV:
            //https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/blob/main/av/audio/frame.pyx

        for (int ch = 0; ch < avFrame->ch_layout.nb_channels; ch++) {
            for (int s = 0; s < avFrame->linesize[0]; s+=sizeof(double)) {
                double value;
                memcpy(&value, &avFrame->data[ch][s], sizeof(double));
                mySamples.push_back(AudioFrameSample{ value });
            }
        }
        av_packet_unref(avPacket);
    }
    for (auto& f : mySamples) {
        for (int ch = 0; ch < 6; ch++) {
            printf("%0.8f,", f[ch]);
        }
        printf("%0.8f\n", f[7]);
    }
    avcodec_free_context(&avCodecCtx);
    av_packet_free(&avPacket);
    av_frame_free(&avFrame);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2) {
        ReadFramesForAudioFile(argv[1]);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: avcodec-simple-frame-extraction [path]\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my experiments, `avCodecCtx->request_sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_DBL` has no effect.
There are all kind of [references](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/libav-user/2020-September/012557.html) saying that it's not working....

Using `av_get_packed_sample_fmt(avCodecCtx->sample_fmt)`, we can see that the sample format is `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT` (float).
Casting from `float` to `double` is not an issue (in case the format is `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16` for example, scaling is required).

---

The loop that stores the samples into `mySamples` is incorrect.
There are few solutions, here is a suggested solution (assume the data is float):

```
AudioFrameSample my_sample{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; //Single sample

for (int s = 0; s < avFrame->linesize[0]; s+=sizeof(float)) {
    for (int ch = 0; ch < avFrame->ch_layout.nb_channels; ch++) { //Channels is the inner loop
        float value = *((float*)(&avFrame->data[ch][s])); //We better use "load operation" than using memcpy.
        my_sample[ch] = value; //Fill all channels
    }

    mySamples.push_back(my_sample);
}
```

The inner loop iterates the channels.
After storing all channels in `my_sample`, we are storing `my_sample` in `mySamples`.

---

Updated code sample:

```
extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
}


#include <array>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

using AudioFrameSample = std::array<double, 8>;


static int ReadFramesForAudioFile(const char* filepath)
{
    //AVCodecContext* avCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(nullptr);
    AVFormatContext* avFmtCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
    AVStream* avFirstAudioStream = nullptr;
    
    AVCodecParameters* avCodecParams = nullptr;
    if (avformat_open_input(&avFmtCtx, filepath, nullptr, nullptr) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file with avformat_open_input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(avFmtCtx, nullptr) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't get stream info with avformat_find_stream_info\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //avCodecCtx->request_sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_DBL;

    //find the index of the first audio stream
    int streamIndex = -1;
    for (int si = 0; si < (int)avFmtCtx->nb_streams; si++) {
        if (avFmtCtx->streams[si]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            avCodecParams = avFmtCtx->streams[si]->codecpar;
            streamIndex = si;
            break;
        }
    }


    //find decoder codec for local stream
    const AVCodec* avCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(avCodecParams->codec_id);
    AVCodecContext* avCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(avCodec);
    avcodec_parameters_to_context(avCodecCtx, avCodecParams);

    avCodecCtx->request_sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_DBL; //<-- Has no effect.

    avcodec_open2(avCodecCtx, avCodec, nullptr);
    if (streamIndex == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No audio streams detected\n");
    }

    avFirstAudioStream = avFmtCtx->streams[streamIndex];
    //no resampling, just use the same sampling rate as the original codec
    //prepare reading data
    AVPacket* avPacket = av_packet_alloc();
    AVFrame* avFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (avFrame == nullptr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating the frame\n");
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<AudioFrameSample> mySamples;

    while (av_read_frame(avFmtCtx, avPacket) >= 0) {
        avcodec_send_packet(avCodecCtx, avPacket);
        avcodec_receive_frame(avCodecCtx, avFrame);
        //TODO: Study and use decoding technique in PyAV:
            //https://github.com/PyAV-Org/PyAV/blob/main/av/audio/frame.pyx

        AVSampleFormat sample_fmt = av_get_packed_sample_fmt(avCodecCtx->sample_fmt);   //AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT

        AudioFrameSample my_sample{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; //Single sample

        if (sample_fmt == AV_SAMPLE_FMT_DBL)
        {
            for (int s = 0; s < avFrame->linesize[0]; s+=sizeof(double)) {
                for (int ch = 0; ch < avFrame->ch_layout.nb_channels; ch++) { //Channels is the inner loop
                    double value;
                    memcpy(&value, &avFrame->data[ch][s], sizeof(double));
                    //mySamples.push_back(AudioFrameSample{ (double)value });
                    my_sample[ch] = value; //Fill all channels
                }

                mySamples.push_back(my_sample);
            }
        }
        else if (sample_fmt == AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT)
        {
            for (int s = 0; s < avFrame->linesize[0]; s+=sizeof(float)) {
                for (int ch = 0; ch < avFrame->ch_layout.nb_channels; ch++) { //Channels is the inner loop
                    //memcpy(&value, &avFrame->data[ch][s], sizeof(float));
                    float value = *((float*)(&avFrame->data[ch][s])); //We better use "load operation" than using memcpy.
                    //mySamples.push_back(AudioFrameSample{ (double)value });
                    my_sample[ch] = value; //Fill all channels
                }

                mySamples.push_back(my_sample);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "sample_fmt is not yet supported by the current implementation\n");
            return 1;
        }

        av_packet_unref(avPacket);
    }

    //Example for playing the raw audio file using FFplay (my input audio file is stereo):
    //ffplay -f f64le -ar 44100 -ac 2 -channel_layout stereo raw_audio.raw
    FILE *ff = fopen("raw_audio.raw", "wb"); //Open binary file for storing the audio samples in raw binary format.

    int nb_channels = avFrame->ch_layout.nb_channels;

    for (auto& f : mySamples) {
        //for (int ch = 0; ch < 6; ch++) {
        for (int ch = 0; ch < nb_channels-1; ch++) {
            //printf("%0.8f,", f[ch]);S
            fwrite(&f[ch], 1, sizeof(f[ch]), ff);    //Write audio sample to binary file
        }        
        //printf("%0.8f\n", f[nb_channels-1]);  //printf("%0.8f\n", f[7]);        
        fwrite(&f[nb_channels-1], 1, sizeof(f[nb_channels-1]), ff); //Write audio sample to binary file
    }

    fclose(ff);

    avcodec_free_context(&avCodecCtx);
    av_packet_free(&avPacket);
    av_frame_free(&avFrame);
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    const char *input_file = "song.mp3";

    ReadFramesForAudioFile(input_file);

    return 0;
}
```

---

The above code sample stores the samples to `raw_audio.raw` file.

With my stereo input file, I could play the audio using FFplay (adjust the arguments as needed):

`ffplay -f f64le -ar 44100 -ac 2 -channel_layout stereo raw_audio.raw`

For testing, I suggest you to start with a stereo MP3 input file (with 44100 sample rate).